# C++ Template specialization. How do you make it choose a specific type?

Tags: c++, generics

```
template <class MyType>
class DataClass
{
public:
   virtual void WriteData(Serialization::Object* obj) override
   {
       obj->Write(m_myData);
   }

private:
   MyType* m_myData;
};
```

Serlialization::Object knows how to write specific types: uint64, double, string.  Its generic `<T>` implementation is left unimplemented with a static_assert.

The problem is when MyType is `int` it chooses the generic implementation.  I want it to choose the `uint64` version.  I tried adding a specialization on DataClass but it still prefers the generic implementation. `<class T>`

```
virtual void WriteData(Serialization::Object* obj) override
{
    WriteData2(obj, m_myData);
}

template <int>
void WriteData2(Serialization::Object* obj, int* data)
{
    uint64 lData = *data;  
    obj->Write(lData);
}

template <class T>
void WriteData2(Serialization::Object* obj, T* data)
{
    obj->Write(*data);
}
```

Note that I've tried various combinations of pointer/non-pointer calls, so I don't think that is the issue.  I tried leaving the `template <>` blank like you do in other specializations and that results in the following error.

> error C2912: explicit specialization 'void
>   DataClass::WriteData2(Serialization::Object *,int)' is not
>   a specialization of a function template

So, my question is how do I get it to choose the correct `uint64` function on Serialization::Object?  I could just implement an int version on Serialization::Object but I don't want to write a specialization for every possible type.

Comment: The error message indicates something completely different than you suspect it does. Nothing to do with `Serialization::Object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following from outside the class:

```
template <>
void DataClass<int>::WriteData2(Serialization::Object* obj, int* data) {
    uint64 lData = *data;  
    obj->Write(lData);
}
```

Comment: Ah!  Very close.  Because DataClass is templatized It just needed the specialization for the original WriteData.  DataClass<int>::WriteData(Serialization::Object* obj) and the generic version.

Thanks so much!